# How to add footnote from the frame title in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I have a Beamer document, and I want to add a footnote, where the number that corresponds to the footnote is at the title of the frame. I have something like this, but it doesn't seem to work as the number two appears just under the title, not next to title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test (work in progress)}\footnotemark
\footnotetext[2]{test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item1
\item Item2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already did the hard work by figuring out that in the frametitle, one need the combination of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`.

Simply add the `\footnotemark` inside the frametitle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test (work in progress)\footnotemark}
\footnotetext[2]{test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item1
\item Item2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @pixel You're welcome! Your code was already sooooo close to working :)

Answer (score 1):

This way works properly when there are more than one footnote:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                             

\begin{frame}{The first footnote here%
              \setcounter{footnote}{0}\footnotemark}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{First}

And the second there\footnote{Second}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer output]